# Linux IFS environment variable

Tags: linux, shell

I read the linux command book which instructs IFS(internal field separator), and when change a IFS it is like this:

```
IFS=$'\n'
```

I don't understand what does the dollar sign mean. Thanks!

Comment: This has nothing to do with `IFS`; it's just that strings prefixed with `$` do C-style escapes expansion.